# Can web methods be overloaded?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have built a regular .NET asmx service. How do i overload web methods in this service?

Comment: The issue is that the compiler will not catch it and the error message does not provide you with much information: "The (x) service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

WS-I (web services interoperability) does not support overloading.

Comment: You can do it by disabling WS-I compatibility, but I can't bring myself to propose that as an answer ;-p To all sensible intents, this is (IMO) the right answer.

Answer (score 17):

You can't really overload a web method. When you think about it, this makes sense because a web method is designed not to rely on underlying technologies such as OO languages, as it can theoretically run in things like COBOL.

While you can write a web method that looks like it can be overloaded, you actually have to assign it a different name, as in:

```
[WebMethod]
public void Add(int x, int y)
{
}
[WebMethod(MessageName="AddFloat")]
public void Add(float x, float y)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The WebMethod attribute takes a MessageName parameter that allows you to "overload" the method.

Answer (score 0):

No. Web Service method names must be unique.