# Error Downloading Metadata from ASMX Service

Tags: asmx

It should be possible (and it looks like it is), but assume I have the following functions in my ASMX web service:

```
     [WebMethod(MessageName = "CreateExternalRpt1")]
    public bool CreateExternalRpt(int iProductId, int iOrderProductId, DateTime dtReportTime, string strReportTitle,
        string strReportCategory, string strReportPrintType, out string strSnapshot, string strApplicantFirst, string strApplicantLast,
        string strApplicantMiddle, string strOwnerLast, string strOwnerMiddle, string strOwnerFirst,
        bool blnCurrentReport, int iOrderId, bool blnFlag, string strCustomerId, string strUserId)
  {
       …
    }


    [WebMethod(MessageName = "CreateExternalRpt2")]
    public bool CreateExternalRpt(int iProductId, int iOrderProductId, DateTime dtReportTime, string strReportTitle,
        string strReportCategory, string strReportPrintType, string strReportSnapshot, string strApplicantFirst, string strApplicantLast,
        string strApplicantMiddle, string strOwnerLast, string strOwnerMiddle, string strOwnerFirst,
        bool blnCurrentReport, int iOrderId, bool blnFlag)
    {
    …
  }
```

With both of these functions defined in my web service, my .NET client app can’t download the metadata and instead throws a generic error message “There was an error downloading…”.

With one of the above methods removed, the .NET client app can successfully download the metadata.

I’ve read that by decorating the WebMethod with a unique name, both functions should be exposed in the service metadata.

This isn’t working.  What am I missing?

Comment: As far as I can see, that should work. Try hitting the service URL from a browser. You may get a clearer error message. Otherwise, make sure your service is built, start it by right-clicking the .asmx file and choosing "View in Browser", then try again. Post the complete error message. You may need to use Fiddler to see what's happening on the wire.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

:) - I'm sure once you think about it a minute or two, you'll realize.

Keep in mind that when you're making a traditional call using SOAP, you know a method at the time of the call but don't know the entire signature. You may expect that it contains params A, B, and C, but you're not 100% sure.

As another poster mentioned... [Can web methods be overloaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522585/can-web-methods-be-overloaded/1522628)

There are several ways to overload methods in ASMX by using message-based routers. However, I've never gone that route and have heard many having issues doing so. I'd recommend WCF for overloads. http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/09/21/overloading-methods-in-wcf.aspx

Comment: -1: That is not the case. See the [`MessageName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.messagename.aspx) property of the `WebMethod` attribute.

Comment: John, you may not realize this, but he is attemptign to get this to work with COM+.